# How to perform 64-bit addition and subtraction using MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I want to perform 64-bit addition and subtraction:

`v1v0(HiLo) = a1a0 + a3a2` using MIPS assembly language (`a1a0(HiLo)` is the first 64-bit number consists of two 32-bit numbers, and `a3a2(HiLo)` is the second)

and I have:

```
$a0 = 0xffffffff
$a1 = 0x0
$a2 = 0x1
$a3 = 0x0
```

I'm a beginner in MIPS, and I'm not sure how to handle carries. Could someone provide a solution with explanation?

Thanks in advance! This is the instruction set that I'm using:

http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/201/SPIM-IO/MIPSrefCard.pdf

Comment: I figured out the addition, but not sure how subtraction works...

Comment: I would be nice if you make explicit that you wanna a subtraction

Comment: why [tag:mips64] tag here? In MIPS64 additions and subtractions are inherently in 64 bits and you don't need anything special to do it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281806/adding-two-64-bit-numbers-in-assembly

Comment: @Meteorite any chance you're a Hopkins student?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To subtrate a number, i.e. `v = a - b` is the same as doing an add with a negative number, i.e., `v = a + (-b)`. But, in integer aritmetic, a negative number is coded as a 2-compliment, that is the same as 1-compliment + 1 and 1-compliment is a bitwise negation.

In this way, we can write that:

```
v1v0 = a1a0 - b1b0
v1v0 = a1a0 + ~b1~b0 + 1
```

so, we can write this in assembly as (assuming b1 = a3 and b0 = a2):

```
add64: addu  $v0, $a0, $a2    # add least significant word
       nor   $t0, $a2, $zero  # ~a2
       sltu  $t0, $a0, $t0    # set carry-in bit (capturing overflow)
       addu  $v1, $t0, $a1    # add in first most significant word
       addu  $v1, $v1, $a3    # add in second most significant word
       jr $ra
#PS: To capture the carry bit in a unsigned sum is equivalent to test if the sum
# can not be contained in a 32 bit register. I.e. if a0 + a2 > 2^32 - 1

sub64: nor $a3, $a3, $zero    # ~b1
       nor $a2, $a2, $zero    # ~b0
       jal add64    # v1v0 = a1a0 + ~b1~b0
         # adding 1 to v1v0
       ori $a0, $v0, 0
       ori $a1, $v1, 0
       ori $a2, $zero, 1
       ori $a3, $zero, 0
       jal add64
       jr $ra
```

---

using your ideas, which, I think you would answer your own question:

```
subu $v0, $a0, $a2 # $v0 = $a0 - $a2 
sltu $v1, $a0, $a2 # $v1 = ($a0 < $a2)? 1:0(subtract 1 if there's a borrow for Lo words) 
subu $a1, $a1, $v1 # $a1 = $a1 - $v1 
subu $v1, $a1, $a3 # $v1 = $a1 - $a3
```

Comment: For addition, I did the same thing. But for subtraction, I think `sub64:
    subu  $v0, $a0, $a2 # $v0 = $a0 - $a2
    sltu $v1, $v0, $a2 # $v1 = ($v0 < $a2)? 1:0(subtract 1 if there's a borrow for Lo words)
    addu $a3, $a3, $v1 # $a3 = $a3 + $v1
    subu $v1, $a1, $a3 # $v1 = $a1 - $a3
 jr $ra` should work. What do you think?

Comment: Try the following values and see if it works: `$a1 = 0, $a0 = 0x8000 0001, $a3 = 0, $a2 = 0x8000 0000`

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. I actually used this one: `# your code here
    subu  $v0, $a0, $a2 # $v0 = $a0 - $a2
    sltu $v1, $a0, $a2 # $v1 = ($a0 < $a2)? 1:0(subtract 1 if there's a borrow for Lo words)
    addu $a3, $a3, $v1 # $a3 = $a3 + $v1
    subu $v1, $a1, $a3 # $v1 = $a1 - $a3`

Comment: Again, you can try with the following values: `$a1 = 0, $a0 = 0, $a3 = 0, $a2 = 1`

Comment: @Amadeus I could be wrong, but to me it looks like the second line of add64 should read `sltu $t0, $v0, $a2` because it appears that you're setting `$t0` arbitrarily based on weather the upper halves of the parameters are greater/less than one another.

Comment: @tuckerchapin I did not remember the logic that I've followed, but it seems incorrect by now, so I have updated my answer to accomplish what I think is correct. In regard with your proposed solution, I guess it would not solve the problem once if a2 = a0 = 0x8000 0000, `sltu $t0, $v0, $a2` would not capture the carry bit

Comment: How do the second and third line capture the carry bit?

Comment: @tuckerchapin is correct; the usual idiom is `sum = a+b`; `carry = sum < a;` or `sum < b` (either one is equally valid because addition is commutative).  That's what GCC does (https://godbolt.org/z/ca9zT5cjM), using just `sltu` as tucker suggested instead of wasting an instruction on NOR.  I'm not sure whether your answer works or not; it seems to be doing `a_low < (-b_low - 1)` which makes no sense to me, and isn't commutative so it seems incorrect unless I'm missing something.  It's certainly inefficient.

Comment: Turns out this is almost correct, just inefficient.  (The operands to `sltu` are backwards: should be `sltu  $t0, $t0, $a0` as shown in El Rico's answer).  The asymmetry of `<` is balanced out by NOTing one of the operands.  Tested with uint8_t so we can check all all possible inputs: https://godbolt.org/z/9KeWdo3sM : `(~b) < a;` is correct, unlike the asm here doing `a < (~b)`.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm add64 should be:

```
   addu  $v0, $a0, $a2    # add least significant word
   nor   $t0, $a2, $zero  # ~a2
   sltu  $t0, $t0, $a0    # **~a2 < a0 to check carry generation**
   addu  $v1, $t0, $a1    # add in first most significant word
   addu  $v1, $v1, $a3    # add in second most significant word
   jr $ra
```

We may check the carry with a0 + a2 > 2^32 - 1, but remember that in binary:

2^n - 1 = a2 + ~a2  (ex: a2 = 0110, ~a2 = 1001, a2 + ~a2 = 1111 = 2^4 - 1, n=4)

Thus, a0 + a2 > a2 + ~a2   =>  a0 > ~a2

Comment: This is correct but less efficient than `sum = a+b;` `carry = sum < a;`.  See [Adding two 64 bit numbers in Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1281806)

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to do exactly what you learned in like second grade when adding multi-digit numbers. Add each "column".

```
 12    89
+34   +33
---   ---
 46   122
```

The first one is easy because no "carrying" happens. In the second case you had to actually add 3 numbers in the tens column: 8 + 3 + 1 (carry from ones column). Then the second column also carried to make 100.

You need to do the same thing but you will be adding 32-bits in each "column". Fortunately since you are in binary, you can only carry one bit from the first column to the second.

Comment: MIPS does not have a carry flag.

Answer (score 0):

The MIPS architecture does not provide a carry flag (nor any other flags!).  According to [this](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_2/5.html) page, an overflow requiring a carry occurs when adding two positive numbers gives a negative number (or vice versa).

Something like `bool carry = (a1[31] == a3[31]) && (v1[31] != a1[31])` translated into MIPS assembly should work.

Comment: Thank you @markgz ! I figured I need something like that, and I'm trying to implement the logic using `sltu`.

Comment: That expression gives you signed overflow, not unsigned carry-out.  e.g. `0xFFFFFFFF` x 2 produces carry-out, but in terms of signed operations it's just `-1 + -1 = -2` without overflow.  One `sltu` after an `addu` can produce the carry-out: [use slt to check unsigned integer addition carry flag mips](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33503676)