# use slt to check unsigned integer addition carry flag mips

Tags: assembly, mips, carryflag

I'm new to Assembly and I know this is a fair easy question.
I supposed to do unsigned integer addition for `$a0` and `$a2` and store the result in `$v0` by checking the carry flag.

The assignment says:

> Use only `addu`, not `add`, for adding and use `slt` for determining if the addition of two unsigned integers produced a carry, without using conditional branch instructions.

Here is my code:

```
addu $v0, $a0, $a2
sltu $t0, $v0, $a0
```

For this code, if a carry is produced, `$t0` equals `1`. 
But the question said use only `slt` to check the carry flag and no conditional branch instruction can be used. I'm a little bit confused about how this is gonna to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. What should happen if you got carry?

Comment: @Jester: the carry should be stored in `$t0`, I take it.

Comment: Yep, just store the carry in _$t0_

Comment: Didn't they actually mean "slt, any of its variants" and consider "sltu" to be a variant? Because testing unsigned wrapping with an actual `slt` makes little sense (it can be done, but in a pointlessly verbose way)

Comment: Well, carry is already in $t0, and no branching has been used. So if `sltu` is allowed, I don't see what the question is?

Comment: The question says that **Use only addu, not add, for adding and use slt for determining if the addition of two unsigned integers produced a carry,
without using conditional branch instructions**

Comment: Is there anything else you may use? Such as `and`/`or`?

Comment: If you must use `slt`, you can do it with four `addu`'s and the `slt` (would destroy one of the operands, which can be recovered with a fifth `addu`)

Comment: I think I can use and or xor.

Comment: MIPS does not have a carry flag. Your code is almost correct, but you should be using `slt` instead of `sltu`, since you want to do a signed comparison rather than an unsigned comparison.

Comment: @markgz if I use _slt_, the value stored in $t0 is 0?

Comment: Consider that `a <u b = (a ^ signbit) <s (b ^ signbit)`, and also that flipping the sign is the same as adding or subtracting 1 to/from it. You can avoid `sltu` that way (and even xor, if you want).

Comment: See also [get unsigned long long addition carry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56027411) for the `sum = a+b;` /  `carry = sum<a;` formula. (or `sum<b` if that's more convenient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the professor said he got the question wrong, using `addu` and `sltu` are fine.