# get unsigned long long addition carry

Tags: c, x86-64, addition, integer-overflow, extended-precision

I want to get the carry bit of adding two unsigned 64-bit integers in c.
I can use x86-64 asm if needed.
code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long long llu;

int main(void){
  llu a = -1, b = -1;
  int carry = /*carry of a+b*/;
  llu res = a+b;
  printf("a+b = %llu (because addition overflowed), carry bit = %d\n", res, carry);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you use GCC or Clang built-ins? `carry = __builtin_add_overflow(a, b, &res)` stores the low bits of the result in `res` and sets `carry` to if overflow occurred. (The function actually returns a `bool` that is `true` or `false`, so assigning it to `carry` will produce 1 or 0.)

Comment: Note that msvc (if that's what you are using) also has a builtin for efficiently handling overflow ([_addcarry_u64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/x64-amd64-intrinsics-list?view=vs-2019)).

Comment: Why do you assing `-1` to an unsigned int number?  That is Undefined Behaviour and you can get anything from that, even a program crash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @EugeneSh. observes, the carry is either 0 or 1.  Moreover, given that `a` and `b` both have the same *unsigned* type, their sum is well defined even if the arithmetic result exceeds the range of their type.  Moreover, the (C) result of the sum will be less than both `a` and `b` when overflow occurs, and greater otherwise, so we can use the fact that C relational operations evaluate to either 0 or 1 to express the carry bit as

```
carry = (a + b) < a;
```

That does not require any headers, nor does it depend on a specific upper bound, or even on `a` and `b` having the same type.  As long as both have unsigned types, it reports correctly on whether the sum overflows the wider of their types or `unsigned int` (whichever is wider), which is the same as their sum setting the carry bit.  As a bonus, it is expressed in terms of the sum itself, which I think makes it clear what's being tested.

Comment: Warning: extending this to `carry_out = (a + b + carry_in) < a` *doesn't* work, because for example `b = 0xFFFF...` and `carry_in = 1` has already produced a carry that you won't detect with `a + 0 < a` being false.  But yes, for add with carry-out but not carry-in, this works great.  And modern compilers often can optimize `c+d + carry` into an `adc` instruction.  You only run into big problems getting compilers to emit a chain of add/adc/adc/adc where you need to use the carry-out from an `adc`, not `add`.

Comment: "As long as both have unsigned types ..." + " and at least one type at least `unsigned`".  `(a + b) < a` insufficient for `unsigned char`

Comment: @chux, "[...]  reports correctly on whether the sum overflows the wider of their types ***or unsigned int*** (whichever is wider)."

Answer (score 8):

Carry can be only `0` or `1`. `1` if there was a wrapping-around and `0` otherwise. 
The wrapping-around is happening in case `a + b > ULONG_LONG_MAX` is true . Note, this is in mathematical terms, not in terms of C, as if `a + b` is actually overflowing, then this will not work. Instead you want to rearrange it to be `a > ULONG_LONG_MAX - b`. So the value of carry will be:

```
carry = a > ULONG_LONG_MAX - b ? 1 : 0;
```

or any preferred style equivalent.

- Don't forget to include `limits.h`.

Comment: The `? 1 : 0` is superfluous.

Comment: @jxh This is depending on the style dictated by the house rules.

Comment: @EugeneSh. What do you mean?

Comment: @Broman By what? Some style guides tell to explicitly state the *integer* values resulting from conditional. Some may even require to have an `if/else` construct here. You are free to pick one.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I get it. Thanks.