# How can I use instructions to determine if a carry out of the MSB

Tags: assembly, mips, bigint, carryflag

How can I use instructions to determine if a carry out of the MSB occurred in executing the MIPS instruction:  `addu   $t2,$t1,$t0` by only examining the contents of the registers before and/or after the instruction executes? is there any instruction that I can use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get unsigned long long addition carry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56027411/get-unsigned-long-long-addition-carry).  Or better, [use slt to check unsigned integer addition carry flag mips](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33503676)

Comment: You could also just look at compiler output for `uint64_t` addition on 32-bit MIPS.