# MIPS assembly - SLT vs SUB

Tags: assembly, optimization, mips

C language:

```
if(a < b) {
   b += a;
}
```

Assume **$t1 = 1, $t2 = b**.

MIPS assembly:

```
       SLT $t0, $t1, $t2
       BEQ $t0, $0, Label
       ADD $t2, $t2, $t1
Label: ...
```

But, it can be reached different way:

```
       SUB $t0, $t1, $t2
       BGEZ $t0, Label
       ADD $t2, $t2, $t1
Label: ...
```

**My question:**

It can be proved that every `SLT` instruction can be replaced by some form of ADD/SUB instructions. So, what's the key usage of instruction `SLT`? Can it be carry out detection as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281806/adding-two-64-bit-numbers-in-assembly) or something else that I missed?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: You can use `slt` to do carry *without* branches. Considering that deeply pipelined processors can have tens of cycles of branch-misprediction penalty, avoiding the branch can produce a considerable performance benefit.

Comment: @EOF Thank you for your answer. Okay, I thought it. But, is there any other usage of SLT instruction that you know?

Comment: MIPS32R2 also adds conditional moves `MOVZ`, `MOVN` which can be used in combination with `SLT` to implement your C code without any branches.

Comment: @markgz Thank you for your answer. Also, isn't be better to perform `SUB` and then conditional jump or conditional skip following instruction (for implement C code without branches and for avoid break pipeline), that will be comparing only with zero (equal, not equal, less, less or equal, greater, greater or equal)?